# Question regarding linear transformations from a vector space to the Reals focusing on images equaling zero [Solved]

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Right now I'm trying to prove a conjecture exercise (ex. 15 in section 3.2 of Lang's Linear Algebra). I am aware that the space being dealt with is the Kernel, but as I have yet to reach that section, I'm trying to prove it without delving into the math in the next section to see what insights it can provide.

$\mathbf{Statement\;of\;the\;Problem:}$ Let V be a vector space and $F:V\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ a linear map. Let $W$ be a subset of $V$ consisting of all elements $v$ such that $F(v)=0$. Assume that $W\neq V$, and let $v_0$ be an element of $V$ which does not lie in $W$. Show that every element of $V$ can be written as a sum $w+cv_0$ with some $w$ in $W$ and some number $c$.

$\mathbf{My\;attempt\;at\;a\;solution:}$ I began by letting $v$ be an arbitrary element in $V$ and breaking the problem into the following cases:

A) $v$ is an element in $W$

B) $v$ is not in $W$ but is a multiple of $v_0$

C) $v$ is not in $W$ and is not a multiple of $v_0$.

Now cases A and B are trivial to prove (for the first, let $w=v$ and $c=0$ and for the second, let $w=0$ and you're good). Case C is tripping me up though. I initially considered taking the tactic of letting $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ being a basis for V and the splitting the basis into sets $B=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_r\}$ and $C=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_s\}$ such that $r+s=n,C\subset W,$and $B=V\setminus C$. From there I split the linear combo of $v$ in terms of $\beta$ into the sums across $B$ and $C$. However, although I can guarantee that the sum that's the linear combination of the elements in $C$ will at least make up a part of the supposed $w$ as referenced by the claim, since $v\neq cv_0$, I'm stuck on how to prove from there that the sum of the elements in $B$ is either the sum of elements which can go into the $w$ term and those that belong in the multiple of $v_0$ or how to prove the leftover part of the sum term is entirely a part of the multiple of $v_0$. Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

NB) Because it's rather trivial to prove W is a subspace of V, we can allow that as a given for this.

Comment: Why introduce bases? (Are the vector spaces even finite-dimensional?) It may help to work out $f(w+cv_0)$.

Comment: Lang introduces the convention in the text that the vector spaces can be assumed to be finite. For now I'm making the same assumption (however, given setup, I suspect that it can be extended in this way, but eye on the ball for now). I did try to work that out. But even then, I come up short as the equivalence of the transformations doesn't mean the pre-image is equivalent (i.e. can't see how $F(v)=cF(v_0)$ implies that $v=cv_0+w$ necessarily).

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: And as for the questions of why introduce bases, given the transformation is not necessarily one to one (or at least I can't prove that), that's where my mind went next. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: If $F(v)=cF(v_0)$ then what can you say about $v-cv_0$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: All I can really see is that $v-cv_0$ would be an element of W.

Comment: I guess it would also be accurate to say in parallel that $v-w$ is not an element of W as well. But is there any way to go from that to $v-w$ is necessarily a multiple of $v_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat proof:

Let $v$ be an arbitrary element of $V$.  Let $w_v = v - \frac{f(v)}{f(v_0)}v_0$.  Note that $w_v$ is an element of $w$.  Verify that $w_v \in w$.  With that, we may state that
$$
v = w_v + \frac{f(v)}{f(v_0)}v_0
$$
which is to say that with $c = \frac{f(v)}{f(v_0)}$, we have the desired result.

Comment: Also considered. But is there any way to do it where the c doesn't necessarily have to depend on the choice of vectors?

Comment: Well, of course $c$ should depend on the choice of $v \in V$.  If our fixed value of $c$ is $c = 0$, this would imply that all elements of $V$ are in $W$ (contrary to the information given).  If we have a *fixed* $c \neq 0$ (and a $v_0 \neq 0$), then the set of vectors of the form $w + cv_0$ is no longer a vector space.

Comment: I guess you're right. I was also trying to consider if $c$ could depend on $w$, but I stumbled onto the fact that a certain choice of $c$ locks in a unique $w$ every time. So since your $c$ works, technically that has to be it. Right?

Still, I guess I was just looking for another way using my method. Too much hubris?

Comment: Nothing about my proof directly points to the existence of a *unique* choice, but indeed $c = f(v)/f(v_0)$ is the unique choice that works for a given $v$.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure out the case C of the proof. To not spoil it, I'll give you a hint of how I went about it.

Let $v=\sum_{i=1}^r x_i(\vec{b_i})+\sum_{i=r+1}^n x_i(\vec{c_i})$ and $v_0=\sum_{i=1}^r y_i(\vec{b_i})+\sum_{i=r+1}^n y_i(\vec{c_i})$ where $B=\{\vec{b_1}...\vec{b_r}\}$ and $C=\{\vec{c_1}...\vec{c_c}\}$ (it should be noted that $n-(r+1)=s$ as defined above). Consider $F(v-v_0)$. What happens if $v-v_0\in W$? If it's not, then clearly $F(v-v_0)\neq 0$. Combine that with the fact that the map is to the reals and $F(v_0)\in\mathbf{R}$ as well as $F(v-v_0)\in\mathbf{R}$ , and you should be good to go.

Want to give special shoutouts to @{Lord Shark the Unknown} and @Omnomnomnom. I don't think I could have gotten to this without your guys's help. Thank you for your input and being there to talk it out. :)

Comment: I will also concede that there is a version of the proof which can be done without bases, and is in fact WAY cleaner. Cheers to your @Lord Shark the Unknown: